# Loading Outlook export TSV into MarkLogic using RecordLoader

Tags: csv, marklogic, nosql

I am getting the following when loading a Microsoft Outlook 2010 inbox export TSV into MarkLogic using RecordLoader. Is this an encoding issue? I have tried other methods (mlcp, Java, XQuery) of loading but all of them have failed due to encoding issues. Is there a way to convert a Microsoft generated TSV file into a MarkLogic compatible file? I've tried some online converters but they have not worked. Also I have tried to convert the file into UTF-8 using Notepad++ but when I click on the "convert to UTF-8" button, all of the data disappears. This is my last try at MarkLogic and will switch to another platform if I can't find a way to load this data. Help!

```
SEVERE: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:277)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:338)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at com.marklogic.recordloader.xcc.DelimitedDataLoader.process(DelimitedDataLoader.java:115)
    at com.marklogic.recordloader.AbstractLoader.call(AbstractLoader.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: This should be possible with MLCP for instance. Can you provide a sample of how your file looks, and how you are calling MLCP? Note that line-ends need to match those from the OS, and the first line contains labels without spaces. You may need to fix that manually to get it going properly. Specifying a tab on command-line can be an issue too, but should be possible with an option_file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RecordLoader defaults to using the Java locale default encoding. But you can set the encoding to match your data. For example set `INPUT_ENCODING=Cp1252` if it's windows 1252 encoding.

`INPUT_ENCODING` is documented (lightly) at http://marklogic.github.io/recordloader/ and the Java encoding names are listed at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html